# Are the lips of this illumination of St. Mary moving?

Tags: catholic-church, optical-illusions

[The Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/holy-miracle-watch-virgin-marys-6113110) reports that a video of footage of an illumination of St. Mary, at St Charbel's Church in Sydney, Australia, appears to have her her lips moving to a prayer:

I'm skeptic... but I don't doubt that people perceive the painting's lips moving.

Are the lips in this video moving?

Comment: I don't see lips moving in that video. It's a video from someone who can't hold his phone (not even a decent camera) still, and with varying light intensity (even flashlights). Combine that with video compression artifacts (maybe even worsened by re-encoding the video as it spreads over the internet) and everyone can see anything he likes in there. As such, the video is not even a claim.

Comment: What sort of evidence would you accept that would definitively answer whether the lips are moving or not?

Comment: Meanwhile, little Jesus is making funny, Danny-Torrance-like movements with his fingers.

Comment: Pixel distortion or compression-artifact issues of the phone video clip might contribute to the babbling Little Jesus kid, the hand of the kid twitching along with Mary’s lips moving and the angels presumably singing along in sync with prayer.